# What criteria need to be met to become a Conservative MP Candidate in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, election, campaigning, conservative-party

What criteria need to be met to become a Conservative MP Candidate in the UK?

I am considering running as an MP in my home town in the next election (2022) as a Conservative candidate.

I am a supporter of the majority of actions by the conservative party and believe running as conservative would allow me the greatest chance of being able to make a difference.

However, I don't know if all of my views fit in the traditional realm of the conservative party and whether any of my beliefs would prevent me from running for the conservative party. My views are staunchly right libertarian and quite far so (I am for the separation of Church and State, I would like to see marijuana legalised in certain circumstances, but I'm very nationalist and would like to see far more emphasis put on the rights of British natives). I'm in favour of banning the wearing of Burkhas and Niqabs in public places. I'm somewhat anti monarchist (at least the way the monarchal system is now) and would like to see the monarchy either be abolished or changed and I don't know if these are beliefs the party would allow.

Any clarifications and links to where I can learn more about criteria regarding beliefs that must be met?

Comment: What is a "British native"?

Comment: @WS2: The [red squirrel](https://www.forestry.gov.uk/forestry/redsquirrel), maybe. It faces competition from the invasive North American grey squirrel.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit The only trouble with the greys being that they are "overpaid, over-sexed, and over here", it has been said.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While anyone meeting the criteria to be an MP (be over 18 and a UK, Irish or Commonwealth citizen and not be otherwise disqualified) can run for election in a constituency by collecting enough signatures and paying a deposit, to run in the name of a party, you must be [selected by them](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-23437111). In the case of the Conservatives, candidates are selected by the local constituency Association from a shortlist approved by a central candidates committee.

The committee has produced a [short handout](https://www.conservatives.com/-/media/CCHQ_Guide-to-becoming-a-Candidate.ashx?) documenting some of the process, but in brief it appears you're likely to need to attend a meeting in your local area, then if they like the look of you, be invited to a more formal Parliamentary Assessment Board. This will require you to provide three referees, pay a £250 fee and have been a Conservative Party member for at least 3 months.

As a new and unknown candidate, it's more likely you'd be put up in an opposition safe seat than a safe Conservative seat or an easily winnable marginal, but as the losers of the [1992 General Election in North West Durham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_West_Durham_(UK_Parliament_constituency)#Elections_in_the_1990s) will attest, that doesn't mean you'll never make it as an MP.

Comment: +1. "If they like the look of you" -- for a parliamentary candidate, presentation and interpersonal skills are as important as ideology, if not more so.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Gives me a good insight into the process. My constituency is a marginal seat so I suppose I would need some experience first in a strong labour constituency. I believe it would be too ambitious even for myself to try and win my seat first go in my home town.